# Bad connection to Google websites when using Teredo

Tags: networking, ipv6, teredo

I need IPv6 connectivity on my computer at work but the ISP does not provide it, so I use Teredo (with Miredo) in order to get an IPv6 address.

It works correctly on most websites but on Google websites (Drive, Youtube, etc.), I get a very strange behavior: the website returns a 200 HTTP code but sometime the HTML output is randomly cut (generally shortly after the  tag).
Although I do contact these websites via their IPv4 address (IPv6 is set as fallback), it happens only when Miredo is running.

I tried to ping these websites but didn't see any packet loss.

Do you have any idea what could cause this? (I am using Firefox, but I don't know if it has something to do with it.)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Teredo is a very unreliable protocol as it relies on third party relay servers. It should never be used in production. Instead, get a proper IPv6 tunnel to e.g. Tunnelbroker.net.